# SQL Server : Extract/Compare Query 1 from Query 2

Tags: sql-server, arrays, compare, subquery

This first query is written that looks for the tickets that are assigned to our staff for a specific group set to a specific status.

```
  SELECT DISTINCT [SENT TO]
  FROM [sdetst].[_SMDBA_].[_TELMASTE_]
  WHERE [_GROUP_] = 1003 and [SEQ_UDSTATUS:] = 1002 and [SENT TO] is not null
```

This second query is written to locate the staff that are currently online and available.

```
  SELECT DISTINCT DESK._ACTIVEUSERS_.[Seq.User] 
  FROM DESK.[Support Staff] INNER JOIN DESK._ACTIVEUSERS_ 
  ON DESK.[Support Staff].Sequence = DESK._ACTIVEUSERS_.[Seq.User]
```

What I am trying to do is get the results in query 1 that are not in query 2. Then after I have gotten this I plan to set those values to null as it would make the tickets unassigned and could be handled by other staff. I intend to set this as a scheduled job that will run every few minutes.

Comment: So what is your problem and your question? Please explain a bit more.

Comment: I previously tried the following, however it did not work because I get multiple results. 

    SELECT DISTINCT [SENT TO] FROM [sdetst].[_SMDBA_].[_TELMASTE_] WHERE [_GROUP_] = 1003 and [SEQ_UDSTATUS:] = 1002 and [SENT TO] is not NULL AND [SENT TO] <> (SELECT DISTINCT DESK._ACTIVEUSERS_.[Seq.User] FROM DESK.[Support Staff] INNER JOIN DESK._ACTIVEUSERS_ ON DESK.[Support Staff].Sequence = DESK._ACTIVEUSERS_.[Seq.User] )

Comment: When I tried the above query I got the following error message.

Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: My question/problem would be that I'm not exactly sure how to get the information to extract only the information that Query 1 provides that is not present in Query 2. The results from this new un written query need to be written in a manner that I can update another table based on these results and then null those values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you used the keyword [except](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) to determine the telMaste records you wish to update?

Something like this?

```
;WITH query1WithoutQuery2 AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT [SENT TO]
  FROM [sdetst].[_SMDBA_].[_TELMASTE_]
  WHERE [_GROUP_] = 1003 and [SEQ_UDSTATUS:] = 1002 and [SENT TO] is not null
  EXCEPT
  SELECT DISTINCT DESK._ACTIVEUSERS_.[Seq.User] 
  FROM DESK.[Support Staff] INNER JOIN DESK._ACTIVEUSERS_ 
  ON DESK.[Support Staff].Sequence = DESK._ACTIVEUSERS_.[Seq.User] 
)
UPDATE telMaste
  SET [SENT TO] = NULL 
FROM 
  [sdetst].[_SMDBA_].[_TELMASTE_] as telMaste 
INNER JOIN 
  query1WithoutQuery2 
on telMaste.[SENT TO] = query1WithoutQuery2.[SENT TO]
WHERE [_GROUP_] = 1003 and [SEQ_UDSTATUS:] = 1002 and [SENT TO] is not null
```